# AndroidCAStore throws NullPointerException warning on 4.2.2 Jellybean

Tags: android, xmpp, keystore, asmack

I am using following code for XMPPConnection to get Keystore certificates

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    conf.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
    conf.setTruststorePassword(null);
    conf.setTruststorePath(null);
}
```

This code works fine and I can authenticate user. But also it throws following exception as a warning

```
W/System.err(18470): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(18470):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
W/System.err(18470):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
W/System.err(18470):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> FileInputStream.java:105)
W/System.err(18470):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
W/System.err(18470):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:871)
W/System.err(18470):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:221)
```

After looking at [source](https://github.com/rtreffer/smack/blob/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smack/ServerTrustManager.java) of ServerTrustManager, I suspect its failing at

```
in = new FileInputStream(configuration.getTruststorePath());
```

Does that mean android is not able to find TruststorePath, if yes, where should I point it to.

All blogs are saying above code should work and you do not need to set path for trust store.

Any idea?

Comment: This issue was resolved once I used latest version of ASmack libraries from their own website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved once I used latest version of ASmack libraries from their own website

Comment: Added +1, really using asmack-android-17-0.8.3.jar (the last one) fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: using last version did not really helped. The error just happens not every time.

Comment: Same experience as Umka here, it just happen less often

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem.
The reason is pretty simple, TrusstorePath is null and thats the problem.

You have to change a few lines in the ServerTrustManager.java in org.jivesoftware.smack

```
if(options.getPassword() != null) {
    password = options.getPassword().toCharArray();
}

if(options.getPath() == null) {
    trustStore.load(null, password);
} else {
    in = new FileInputStream(options.getPath());
    trustStore.load(in, password);
}
```

instead of the

```
in = new FileInputStream(configuration.getTruststorePath());
```

And i added

```
InputStream in = null;
char[] password = null;
```

to the top of the synchronized block.

I notified the owner of https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack

Comment: Hi, well you still use "trustStore.load(null, password);" and if truststore is null then you get a nullpointer exception.

Comment: I only tried to fix this for my AndroidCAStore problem :) The bug is reported in asmack upstream. So lets hope they fix in appropriate.